# why my code java.lang.StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

```
private void findRute(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int counter)
    {
        try
        {
            if((x1 == x2) && (y1 == y2))
            {
                if(this.min > counter)
                {
                    this.min = counter;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(map[x1-1][y1] == 0)
                {
                    this.findRute(x1 - 1, y1, x2, y2, counter + 1);
                }
                if(map[x1+1][y1] == 0)
                {
                    this.findRute(x1 + 1, y1, x2, y2, counter + 1);
                }
                if(map[x1][y1 + 1] == 0)
                {
                    this.findRute(x1, y1 + 1, x2, y2, counter + 1);
                }
                if(map[x1][y1 - 1] == 0)
                {
                    this.findRute(x1, y1 - 1, x2, y2, counter + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException z)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should remove the try/catch block, or at least print the stack trace, otherwise you don't notice when an exception occurs.

Comment: @michael667 The exception catch is a lazy-man's bounds check here. It's a bad coding practice but it isn't what is causing the overflow.

Comment: Please specify the values that `map` will hold.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say the map consists entirely of zeroes, and you're in the top left corner. You're going to move one step to the right, then one step to the left, then one step to the right again, and so on.

You need to somehow mark the cells you've already visited, to prevent the infinite recursion.

Also, the catching of `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is not such a good idea:

- firstly, I wouldn't consider it good style: if later on you were to add some code inside the `try` block that could also throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, your code would begin failing silently;
- secondly, if the first check (`map[x1-1][y1]`) is out of bounds, you're going to skip of the remaining checks;

Comment: is it right that i should make boolean[][] status to mark that i have gone there? and where i put the status in my code?
thx for watching my quetion :)

Answer (score -1):

probably you try to access the -1 index or length+1

think what happen in the edge

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct. in this case probably it is a infinite recursion problem.